# How to find out if all records from table A exists in table B using an attribute?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table that contains Lists for users, the number of the list for the user(1,2,3...) and the treasure_no that is contained in that particular list.

I got another table "LookingFor" (a connection table between Treasure and User) that stores the status of the treasure finding(F-FOUND, NF - NOT FOUND, NM-NEED MAINTENANCE) fields are:User_name,Treasure_NO,Status.

I am trying to find the people that has all their treasures in their lists(the treasure_no is a fk to table Treasure) Found by them in the table "LookingFor"
(Found condition is defined as either F OR NM).
and also that they have 2 or more different lists(can be isolated by the number of the list per user)

My code now is this:

```
SELECT LF.user_detail_Name
            FROM(SELECT LC.user_name_detail AS NAME,LC.tressure_No AS T_NO,LC.num_Of_List_User AS LIST_NO
                 FROM dbo.tblListContains AS LC ) AS LIST INNER JOIN dbo.tblLookingFor AS LF
            ON LIST.NAME = LF.user_detail_Name

           WHERE LIST.NAME NOT IN(SELECT LIST3.user_name_detail
                                            FROM(SELECT LC.user_name_detail,LC.tressure_No
                                             From dbo.tblListContains as LC

                                              EXCEPT

                                              SELECT LF.user_detail_Name,LF.tressure_No
                                              FROM dbo.tblLookingFor AS LF)AS LIST3)

           AND LIST.NAME IN (SELECT LIST4.user_name_detail
                             FROM(SELECT LC.user_name_detail,LC.tressure_No
                                 From dbo.tblListContains as LC

                                              INTERSECT

                                              SELECT LF.user_detail_Name,LF.tressure_No
                                              FROM dbo.tblLookingFor AS LF
                                              WHERE LF.Status_finding = 'F' OR
                                              LF.Status_finding = 'NM')AS LIST4)

           GROUP BY LF.user_detail_Name
           HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT LIST.LIST_NO))>=2
```

My issue is that I am unable to make sure that every treasure someone added into his list/s was found by him, if I could get this Group isolated and just ask if the person I am going over his record now (in table ListContains) is in this group I am done.

Example of what I want:

ON TblListContains there are the following entries:

AAA(USER OF LIST),1(NUMBER OF LIST FOR USER),1(TREASURE_NO)

AAA,2,2

AAA,1,3

BBB,1,2

ON TblLookingFor there are the following entries:

1(Treasure number),AAA(user name),F(status),testing(comment),07/08/2016(date),2(level of hideout ranked by user),3(level of terrain)

2,AAA,NM,testing2,07/08/2016,2,4

3,AAA,F,testing3,07/08/2016,2,4

2,BBB,NF,testing4,07/08/2016,2,4

I want to return only AAA (cause he has at least 2 lists and has found all the treasures in his lists)

I will also add the table scheme for your convenience:

[image: table scheme]

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Treasures, users, lists . . . it gets confusing without seeing data.

Comment: just added what you request.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you use an example with two tables: T1 & T2 and attribute "A". Than your question would be shorter and more people would going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might of got it together.

here is the solution I came up with:

```
   SELECT LIST.NAME
            FROM(SELECT LC.user_name_detail AS NAME,LC.tressure_No AS T_NO,LC.num_Of_List_User AS LIST_NO
                 FROM dbo.tblListContains AS LC ) AS LIST 

           WHERE LIST.NAME IN  (SELECT LIST4.user_name_detail
                             FROM(SELECT LC.user_name_detail,LC.tressure_No
                                 From dbo.tblListContains as LC

                                              INTERSECT

                                              SELECT LF.user_detail_Name,LF.tressure_No
                                              FROM dbo.tblLookingFor AS LF
                                              WHERE LF.Status_finding = 'F' OR
                                              LF.Status_finding = 'NM')AS LIST4 INNER JOIN
                                              dbo.tblListContains AS LC
                                              ON LIST4.user_name_detail = LC.user_name_detail
                                              AND LIST4.tressure_No = LC.tressure_No
                                            GROUP BY LIST4.user_name_detail
                                    HAVING COUNT(LIST4.tressure_No) = (SELECT COUNT(LC.tressure_No)
                                                                       FROM dbo.tblListContains AS LC
                                                                       WHERE LIST4.user_name_detail = LC.user_name_detail))                                       
GROUP BY LIST.NAME
HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT LIST.LIST_NO))>=2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request correctly we would just have to outer join all "found" LF records to the LC records. We then group by user and check ...

- whether all LC records have a "found" LF record and
- whether the number of lists is at least 2.

Here is the query:

```
select lc.user_name_detail
from dbo.tbllistcontains lc
left join dbo.tbllookingfor lf on  lf.user_name_detail =  lc.user_name_detail
                               and lf.tressure_no      =  lc.tressure_no
                               and lf.status_finding   in ('F', 'NM')
group by lc.user_name_detail
having count(*) = count(lf.user_name_detail) -- all found
and count(distinct lf.list_no) >= 2; -- two or more lists
```